# Query from SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can anyone help me convert this SQL statement into MySQL, because i'm getting syntax error when i tried to run it from MySQL.

```
SELECT
    a.userid,
    CAST(a.checktime AS VARCHAR) AS timein,
    ISNULL(CAST(b.checktime AS VARCHAR),'NO TIMEOUT') AS timeout
FROM    timein a
LEFT JOIN timeout b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE   ISNULL(CAST(b.checktime),'NO TIMEOUT') = 'NO TIMEOUT'
```

Comment: Replace `ISNULL` By `IFNULL`

Comment: Add the error message please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()` which is SQL-Server syntax.

```
SELECT
    a.userid,
    a.checktime AS timein,
    COALESCE(b.checktime,'NO TIMEOUT') AS timeout
FROM    timein a
LEFT JOIN timeout b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE   COALESCE(b.checktime,'NO TIMEOUT') = 'NO TIMEOUT'
```

Comment: thanks, but still getting syntax error near here    CAST(a.checktime as varchar) AS timein,
    COALESCE( CAST(b.checktime as varchar),'NO TIMEOUT') AS timeout

Comment: What type is `checktime` column ?

Comment: i declared it as Varchar

Comment: @Seryu Then why the hell do you cast it to varchar? Try the query now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.userid,
    CAST(a.checktime AS CHAR(100)) AS timein,
    IFNULL(CAST(b.checktime AS CHAR(100)),'NO TIMEOUT') AS timeout
FROM    timein a
LEFT JOIN timeout b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE   IFNULL(CAST(b.checktime),'NO TIMEOUT') = 'NO TIMEOUT';
```

- You need to cast as `char` datatype. (you need to put the correponding length of the varchar column in `CHAR(LENGTH)` )
- `ISNULL` function in MySQL takes one parameter whereas in `SQL SERVER` it takes two. You should use `IFNULL`
  or `COALESCE` (as sagi mentioned).

**Note about `CAST` :**

> The CAST() function converts a value of any type into a value that has
>   a specified type. The target type can be any one of the following
>   types: BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, TIME,DECIMAL, SIGNED, UNSIGNED .